# Android BLE device receives results extremely irregularly

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

My beacon (SensorTag CC2541) is an advertiser broadcasting its information 10 times a second.

My Android app scans with a `BluetoothLeScanner`. Mostly the time between each scan result registered by my `BluetoothLeScanner` is about 0.1 second to 0.6 seconds, which is completely fine. But sometimes (every 5ish seconds) the time between each scan result is more than 2 seconds. Sometimes up to 5. Which puts my application off as I'm in need for quick detection of the beacon.

I do not batch scan, I simply handle each scan result as it comes in.

I tried to combat this irragularity issue by creating my own `scanSettings` and forcing the reportDelay to 0 and the scan mode to low latency. However, when I implement it with the code below, my scanner only picks up each beacon ONCE. But when using the `mLeScanner.startScan(scanCallback)` without `scanSettings` I get several results from the same beacon (albeit at inconsistent intervals as explain above). Does anyone have any idea what this issue might be caused by?

```
BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
BluetoothLeScanner mLeScanner = mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();

ScanSettings.Builder scanSettingsBuilder = new ScanSettings.Builder();
scanSettingsBuilder.setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY);
scanSettingsBuilder.setReportDelay(0);
scanSettingsBuilder.setCallbackType(ScanSettings.CALLBACK_TYPE_ALL_MATCHES);
ScanSettings scanSettings = scanSettingsBuilder.build();

ScanCallback scanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
        super.onScanResult(callbackType, result);
        //Handle result
    }

    @Override
    public void onBatchScanResults(List<ScanResult> results) {
        super.onBatchScanResults(results);
        //Not used, any code I put here never gets run
    }

    @Override
    public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {
        super.onScanFailed(errorCode);
    }
};

mLeScanner.startScan(null, scanSettings, scanCallback);
```

The result shows callbackType = 1, and the scanSettings does the same when I log it before the mLeScanner.startScan(....), so as far as I can understand that's not the issue.

UPDATE: It seems like the only-scanned-once issue when using scanSettings is because my beacons have connectable mode enabled. I will try to disable them tomorrow.

**However, will overriding the scanSettings like that even help my irregularity situation?**

Comment: I faced similar problem while working in ble based technology in rpi. If your android device is using bluez as btstack; it automatically pauses in between scan windows. To minimize it you need to change the scan interval and window of your android device. I am not sure about how bluedroid handles this.

Comment: You mean programatically or manually on Bluetooth settings?

Comment: I am afraid you have to do it manually or you can check the status of the issue by changing your advertising interval from 100ms to 30ms. btw - what btstack is your android phone is using

Comment: Tbh I have no idea what btstack (I guess it means bluetooth stack) or bluez is, so I can't really answer your question. How do I find out?

Comment: It seems like I might have bluedroid

Comment: is changing the advertising interval to 30ms gives you improved performance? (e,g faster discovery)? What I said regarding scan interval / window holds for bluez bt stack, for bluedroid I am not sure as their bt controller specific module is implemented by vendor, which is proprietary.

Comment: one hackish solution (very quick) can be to scan for 2-3 sec then cancel the scan and immediately issue the scan command again. with low advertising interval + this method your device should be discovered continuously and immediately.

Comment: I experienced the same issues and from my point it depends on the phone model. Nexus 7 and Moto G2 for example have this huge pausing during scans, Nexus 5 and 9 work fine. I also played around a lot with scan settings and scan durations, but could not find a solution besides excluding certain devices...

Comment: @pewpew Was disabling "connectable mode" on your beacons a solution to your problem?